# Divide value by sum of another column in PivotTable without Query

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a table that looks like this

```
|---------------------------------|
| Date | User | Value A | Value B |
|------|------|---------|---------|
| Day1 |  U1  |   A111  |   B111  |
|------|------|---------|---------|
| Day1 |  U1  |   A112  |   B112  |
|------|------|---------|---------|
| Day2 |  U1  |   A121  |   B121  |
|------|------|---------|---------|
| Day2 |  U2  |   A221  |   B221  |
|---------------------------------|
```

I need to create a PivotTable that displays for each User : Sum of his Value A / Sum of all Value B.

Obtaining some like that :

```
|---------------------------------------|
| Date | User |    Value A / Value B    |
|------|------|-------------------------|
| Day1 |  U1  | (A111+A112)/(B111+B112) |
|------|------|-------------------------|
| Day2 |  U1  |      A121+(B121+B221)   |
|------|------|-------------------------|
| Day2 |  U2  |      A221+(B121+B221)   |
|---------------------------------------|
```

I can only use default Microsoft Excel 2010 and can not install any add-on, so I'm using only VBA and Pivot Tables to keep the sheets always updated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Pivot tables do not work with custom functions, you're left with VBA. There you can use something like:

```
Sub getValues()
Dim LastRow As Long
  Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(8)
  Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(9)
  Range("H:I").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes

  With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
  End With

  For i = 2 To LastRow
    Cells(i, 10).Formula = "=" & "SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,H" & i & ",B:B,I" & i & ")/SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,H" & i & ",B:B,I" & i & ")"
  Next i
End Sub
```